Upgrading Spring Boot from 3.1.3. to 3.1.4 truncates content after gzip decompress
When upgrading from Spring Boot 3.1.3 to 3.1.4 (also tried higher), calls to our API has our data being truncated when gzipped data is being decompressed.
After some debugging I've found out that this change that came with 3.1.4, which is for Spring Framework, is the culprit: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/30942
When StringHttpMessageConverter.readInternal gets called, the Content-Length is only 377 bytes (compressed bytes), while the uncompressed is 1076. I then end up with a truncated body.
The application calling us is not really something I have access to, but this is the function they use to compress before calling us:
private fun getGzip(body: ByteArray?): ByteArray {
    ByteArrayOutputStream().use { byteStream ->
        GZIPOutputStream(byteStream).use { zipStream ->
            zipStream.write(body!!)
            zipStream.finish()
            return byteStream.toByteArray()
        }
    }
}

This is the code we use in our application do decompress the data:
@Component
@Order(0)
open class GzipDecompressFilter : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    override fun doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
        var httpServletRequest = request

        val contentEncoding = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Content-Encoding")
        if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.indexOf("gzip") > -1) {
            try {
                val decompressStream: InputStream = StreamHelper.decompressStream(httpServletRequest.inputStream)
                httpServletRequest = object : HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest) {
                    override fun getInputStream(): ServletInputStream {
                        return DecompressServletInputStream(decompressStream)
                    }

                    override fun getReader(): BufferedReader {
                        return BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(decompressStream))
                    }
                }
            } catch (_: IOException) {
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, response)
    }
}

open class DecompressServletInputStream(private val inputStream: InputStream) : ServletInputStream() {
    override fun read(): Int {
        return inputStream.read()
    }

    override fun isFinished(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun isReady(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun setReadListener(listener: ReadListener?) {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
}

object StreamHelper {

    private const val GZIP_ID1: Byte = 0x1f

    private const val GZIP_ID2 = 0x8b.toByte()

    fun decompressStream(input: InputStream?): InputStream {
        val pushbackInput = PushbackInputStream(input, 2)
        val signature = ByteArray(2)
        pushbackInput.read(signature)
        pushbackInput.unread(signature)
        return if (signature[0] == GZIP_ID1 && signature[1] == GZIP_ID2) {
            GZIPInputStream(pushbackInput)
        } else pushbackInput
    }
}

This is the Controller-class where the endpoints are being called (cut out most for brevity):
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(
    value = ["/api"],
    method = [RequestMethod.POST],
    consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE],
    produces = ["application/json;charset=UTF-8"]
)
class ServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var serviceBi: ServiceBi

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper


    @RequestMapping(value = ["/endpoint"])
    @ApiResponse(content = [Content(schema = Schema(hidden = true))])
    fun invokeEndpoint(@RequestBody req: request): Response {
        try {
            objectMapper.readValue(request, Request::class.java).run {
                return serviceBi.endpoint(this)!!
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        }
    }
}

Made a test to replicate the error using my consumers gzip-method:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ServiceControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private val port = 8989

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var restTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @Test
    fun testEndpoint() {
        val response = restTemplate.exchange(
            "http://localhost:$port/api/endpoint",
            HttpMethod.POST,
            HttpEntity(getGzip(request().toByteArray()), makeHttpHeaders()),
            String::class.java
        )
    }

    private fun makeHttpHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
        val httpHeaders = HttpHeaders()
        httpHeaders.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
        return httpHeaders
    }

    private fun getGzip(body: ByteArray?): ByteArray {
        ByteArrayOutputStream().use { byteStream ->
            GZIPOutputStream(byteStream).use { zipStream ->
                zipStream.write(body!!)
                zipStream.finish()
                return byteStream.toByteArray()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun request(): String = "long json"
}

I did try to implement the accepted answer here without any luck: Spring Boot Put payload with gzip compressed is getting truncated after upgrade to 3.2.0 from 3.1.9
I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to solve this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You tried without luck. What did you try as that is the only way to fix it. Replacing your filter with the one from the answer should work.

Does this answer your question? Spring Boot Put payload with gzip compressed is getting truncated after upgrade to 3.2.0 from 3.1.9
